# validation form return me error, $form->isValid()

Tags: forms, symfony

I don't understand why my form return to me a error

This value is not valid

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
var_dump($form->isValid());
$this->get('session')
->setFlash('notice', 'Le modifiche sono state salvate!');

            }else{
                var_dump($form->getErrors());

            }
```

I have tried to`var_dump($form->getErrors());` return to me

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(Symfony\Component\Form\FormError)#511 (2) { ["messageTemplate":protected]=> string(23) "This value is not valid" ["messageParameters":protected]=> array(0) { } } }
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Please post the contents of your `$form` object.

Comment: We can gladly help if you would post more code. Please post all of the code to initialize `$form`.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error few days ago. If you use embedded forms, the error may come from a field of one of the embedded forms.

I agree with leek, post the contents of your form type object.

Comment: The problems is because one field return Null given.
this i have because i make dinamic select and i change the select form with jquery.....but i not know how fix the problem, i need select Dynamic for Regione City.....